# what does the error mean when I am compiling c++ with g++ compiler?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, compiler-errors

using the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec;
    for(vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix != 10; ix++)
    {
        ivec.push_back(ix);
    }
    vector<int>::iterator mid = (ivec.begin() + ivec.end()) / 2;
    cout << *mid << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error compiling with g++:

```
iterator_io.cpp: In function `int main()':
iterator_io.cpp:13: error: no match for 'operator+' in '(&ivec)->std::vector<_Tp,               _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]() + (&ivec)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/stl_iterator.h:654: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator+(const typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type&) const [with _Iterator = int*, _Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/stl_bvector.h:261: note:                 std::_Bit_iterator std::operator+(ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_iterator&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/stl_bvector.h:345: note:                 std::_Bit_const_iterator std::operator+(ptrdiff_t, const std::_Bit_const_iterator&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.5/../../../../include/c++/3.4.5/bits/stl_iterator.h:765: note:                 __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> __gnu_cxx::operator+(typename __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::difference_type, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&) [with _Iterator = int*, _Container = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >]
```

I know the ivec.end() can not be used as a normal vector element. But I can't understand what the error information means...something about operator+?

Comment: +1 for a well-asked, well-formatted, properly-tagged first question.

Comment: +1 for including a short, complete sample program. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You **cannot add two iterators** together.

`operator+` is not defined for two iterators, because that operation wouldn't make sense. Iterators are a kind of generalization over pointers - they point to the specific element stored in container. At which element the sum of iterators is pointing?

However, when you use a vector, you can add **integers to iterators**, like that:

```
vec.begin() + vec.size() / 2
```

and that is why you have `candidates are: (...)` in your error message, followed by some definitions of `operator+`.

In your case the best, and cleanest way will be not using the iterators, but simple **getting the value from specified position**:

```
int mid = vec[vec.size() / 2];
```

Comment: Using `at` here is unorthodox, to say the least. In the current case, there can *never* be an access error, so why guard against it?

Comment: I agree, `at()` changed to `[]`.

Answer (score 22):

You cannot add iterators. What you can do:

```
vector<int>::iterator mid = ivec.begin() + distance(ivec.begin(), ivec.end()) / 2;
```

Comment: Won't `distance(vector::begin, vector::end)` be the same as `vector::size`?

Comment: @PeterWood - In this case, yes. But distance also works for other containers, not just vector.

Comment: @PeterWood: I think the idea is, that you could use any two iterators, `b` and `e`, and `b+distance(b,e)/2` would give you the position in the middle of `b` and `e`. So, it's a bit more general.

Comment: @Henrik: as per `23.2.1 General container requirements`, all containers shall have a `size()`. For vector, it might make no performance distance.

Comment: @bitmask: Well, that presumes that you'd have `operator+(Iter, offset_t)` (i.e. random iterators.), and for those you can just use `operator-(Iter, Iter)`. So the fully-portable and efficient alternative is `ivec.begin + (ivec.end()-ivec.begin())/2;`. This is valid even when the container is empty.

Comment: @MSalters: `std::distance()` is typically specialised for random-access iterators to use `operator-` anyway, by way of `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: @JonPurdy: True, as is `std::advance` (which is specialized to use  `operator+`). Perhaps I should make it a bit more explicit: To be consistent, use `std::advance` in conjunction with `std::distance`, and `operator+` with `operator-`.

Answer (score 7):

It simply means that `vector` iterators have no addition operator (`+`). You cannot add `ivec.begin()` and `ivec.end()`.

To get the middle element, you can simply use the subscript operator:

```
cout << ivec[ivec.size()/2] << endl;
```

If you insist on using an iterator, you can get an iterator that points to the middle in this fashion:

```
vector<int>::iterator mid = ivec.begin();
mid += ivec.size()/2;
cout << *mid << endl;
```

You can do this, because the `vector` iterator is a random access iterator (in all implementations I'm aware of it encapsulates an actual pointer to the raw container-data).

Comment: In many debug builds such as MSVC's, `vector<T>::iterator` holds the array bounds as well. That means it will catch most out-of-bounds errors in debugging.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but my point was, that it also holds the pointer to the raw sequence (array).

Answer (score 6):

You can't add iterators.

What you'll want to use is a combination of [std::distance()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) and [std::advance()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/):

```
vector<int>::iterator mid = std::advance(ivec.begin(), std::distance(ivec.begin(), ivec.end()) / 2);
```

Why use `std::advance()` instead of the iterator's addition operator?  `std::advance()` works optimally regardless of the iterator type (random access, forward only, bidirectional, etc), so if you switch from `std::vector` to `std::list` the above code can remain the same, and still work optimally.

Comment: This is not optimal for `std::list` anymore. In C++11, `std::distance(ilist.begin(), ilist.end())` can still be O(N) but `ilist.size()` returns the same value in O(1).

Comment: @MSalters: interesting!  Why the change?

Comment: C++03 allowed both, with a necessary tradeoff on `splice`. As a result, portable code had to treat both `size` and `splice` as O(N). C++11 made `size` portably O(1).

Answer (score 3):

not possible to add two iterators

use at to get the middle item:

ivec.at(ivec.size()/2);

Comment: @Henrik: Lack of context. This will: `cout << ivec.at(ivec.size()/2) << endl;`. If you know `ivec` is not empty, you can also write `cout << ivec[ivec.size()/2] << endl;`

Answer (score 2):

You can not add two iterators together, because iterators are not integers. That's what the error message means. If you want to access the element in the middle of a vector, use `ivec[ivec.size() / 2]`.