# c++: vector::erase called with an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, struct, iterator, erase

I am working on a vector of structs.

When I am trying to call this function with iterator, like this:

```
vec2.erase (vec2.begin()+iter2);
```

it sends me this error:

```
"no match for 'operator+' in '(+vec2)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = wordstype, _Alloc = std::allocator<wordstype>]() + iter2'"
```

Can I send an iterator (or any other parameter)?
If yes, what is the problem?

Comment: You are confusing iterators and offsets :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add [iterator to iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9684875/13767).

`iter2` already points to the concrete place in a vector, so you can write:

```
iter2 = vec2.erase(iter2);
```

instead.

Comment: Iterator is invalidated when you erase element pointed by this iterator, so the `erase` method returns a new one - it might be useful.

Comment: thank you very much! my poblem was a bad use of iterators arithmetic. you helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! The preferred way of saying thanks is upvoting and accepting answers. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Yes `erase` can work with iterator and the code will look like:

```
erase(itr2);
```

You can also do:

```
erase(vec2.begin() + 3);
```

However the iterators do not declare `operator+` so your call is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add together two iterators, which makes no sense.

Post your code and explain what your are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe doesn't seem to have anything with `std::vector<>::erase`, according to the error message.

The expression the compiler has problems with is `vec2.begin() + iter2`. Apparently, `iter2` in your case is an iterator. `vec2.begin()` is also an iterator. You cannot add one iterator to another. It simply makes no sense. Hence the error.

What are you trying to do by `vec2.begin() + iter2`? If `iter2` is indeed an iterator, why are you trying to add it to `vec2.begin()`?